# Simple custom linked list in Fortran - Unexpected behavior

Tags: list, linked-list, fortran

I'm trying to create a very simple linked list "class" in Fortran. I've based my Fortran code in the following C example:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/learn_c_by_examples/simple_linked_list_program_in_c.htm

Sometimes I compile and run the code and I get the expected output, a "list" containing nodes linking to other nodes, with the ordered values:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

However, some other times, **with the same exact code**, I get something like:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, ... ! or
5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...
```

My guess is some memory allocation issue? I'm new to Fortran and new to using pointers and I simply don't know where to start to debug these kinds of problems...

**class_list.f90**

```
MODULE CLASS_LIST

    PRIVATE

    TYPE :: NODE
        REAL :: VALUE
        TYPE(NODE), POINTER :: NEXT
    END TYPE

    TYPE, PUBLIC :: LIST
        TYPE(NODE), POINTER :: HEAD
        CONTAINS
        PROCEDURE :: APPEND
    END TYPE

    CONTAINS

    SUBROUTINE APPEND(THIS, VALUE)
        CLASS(LIST), INTENT(INOUT) :: THIS
        REAL, INTENT(IN) :: VALUE
        TYPE(NODE), ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: LINK
        ALLOCATE(LINK)
        LINK.VALUE = VALUE
        LINK.NEXT => THIS.HEAD
        THIS.HEAD => LINK
    END SUBROUTINE

END MODULE
```

**main.f90**

```
PROGRAM MAIN

    USE CLASS_LIST

    TYPE(LIST) :: A
    INTEGER :: I

    DO I = 1, 5, 1
        CALL A.APPEND(REAL(I))
    END DO

END PROGRAM
```

**Expected behavior (main local variables in Visual Studio):**

[image]

**Unexpected behavior example (main local variables in Visual Studio):**

[image]

Comment: Firstly note this is not Fortran not C, so % is used to select a structure component in standard Fortran. Secondly I think this is because your allocatable array, being of scope local to the subroutine, gets automatically deallocated when you return. But in a hurry and let me check if Target changes that before I answer properly, I very rarely use pointers.

Comment: No, target does not change anything. Never return pointers to local variables, classical beginner error also in C. One should just allocate `LINK` as a pointer.

Comment: At the very least, you should initialize the pointer component as `HEAD => null()`, else you have undefined memory. Then, the fact that the subroutine declare the node as `allocatable` implies that the variable `link` becomes automatically deallocated on exit of the subroutine. You should make it a `pointer`.

Comment: This is a better example you can learn from, it is written in Fortran with very good explanation. **Spoiler alert:** the page starts with the code, you will want to skip that and scroll down, roughly a third of the page, for the main article with examples not to spoil your learning (if your aim is to learn, of course). Here is the link https://gist.github.com/n-s-k/de4af7ce6cc8f2c85e4b33cedb51fd88

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three problems, as suggested in the comments

1. In Fortran the structure component selector is `%`, ***NOT*** `.` . Thus your program contains syntax errors
2. In Fortran when an `allocatable` array goes out of scope it is automatically deallocated, unless it has the `save` attribute. This is a good thing as it means memory leaks using allocatable arrays are not possible, but it hurts you here as when you exit the append routine the array `LINK` is deallocated, so you lose your data. This is not what you want, and you end up with a dangling pointer - and so any behaviour is possible, including even appearing to work. You can avoid this here by using a pointer instead of an allocatable array. This works here as pointers are *not* deallocated automatically on going out of scope, but it does mean memory leaks and other strange behaviour is much more likely, so generally you should try to use allocatable arrays rather than pointers wherever possible.
3. In Fortran the initial association status of a pointer is undefined unless you initialise it. As undefined pointers can lead to strange behaviour it is best to initialise explicitly using `=> null()`

In fact once you have fixed item 1 gfortran at least can tell you there is a problem if you turn on all the warning flags. The below contains this fix, and also a printing routine which you omit. Look at the warning produced by the compiler:

```
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ cat link_alloc.f90
Module CLASS_LIST

  Private

  Type :: NODE
     Real :: Value
     Type(NODE), Pointer :: NEXT
  End Type NODE

  Type, Public :: LIST
     Type(NODE), Pointer :: HEAD
   Contains
     Procedure :: APPEND
     Procedure :: Print
  End Type LIST

Contains

  Subroutine APPEND(THIS, Value)
    Class(LIST), Intent(INOUT) :: THIS
    Real, Intent(IN) :: Value
    Type(NODE), Allocatable, Target :: LINK
    Allocate(LINK)
    LINK%Value = Value
    LINK%NEXT => THIS%HEAD
    THIS%HEAD => LINK
  End Subroutine APPEND

  Subroutine Print( this )

    Class( list ), Intent( In ) :: this

    Call descend( this%head )

  Contains

    Recursive Subroutine descend( head )

      Type( node ), Intent( In ) :: head

      Write( *, '( f5.0, 1x )' ) head%value

      If( Associated( head%next ) ) Then
         Call descend( head%next )
      End If

    End Subroutine descend

  End Subroutine Print

End Module CLASS_LIST

Program MAIN

  Use CLASS_LIST

  Type(LIST) :: A
  Integer :: I

  Do I = 1, 5, 1
     Call A%APPEND(Real(I))
  End Do

  Call a%print

End Program MAIN
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g link_alloc.f90 -o link_alloc
link_alloc.f90:26:4:

     THIS%HEAD => LINK
    1
Warning: Pointer at (1) in pointer assignment might outlive the pointer target [-Wtarget-lifetime]
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $
```

The English is a little cryptic, but what it is really telling you about is point 2 above - as the array is about to be deallocated the pointer outlives what it points at. Compiler warnings are really useful, learn how to use them! Similarly the run time checks `(-fcheck=all)` indicate how broken everything is:

```
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./link_alloc 
   0.

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f470401f4af in ???
#1  0x7f4704ca3c49 in get_float_string
    at ../../../gcc-7.4.0/libgfortran/io/write_float.def:1065
#2  0x7f4704ca4fe7 in write_float_0
    at ../../../gcc-7.4.0/libgfortran/io/write.c:1597
#3  0x7f4704c9c9b4 in formatted_transfer_scalar_write
    at ../../../gcc-7.4.0/libgfortran/io/transfer.c:2041
#4  0x7f4704c9cf4c in formatted_transfer
    at ../../../gcc-7.4.0/libgfortran/io/transfer.c:2279
#5  0x40098a in descend
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/link_alloc.f90:41
#6  0x4009a9 in descend
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/link_alloc.f90:43
#7  0x4009d2 in __class_list_MOD_print
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/link_alloc.f90:33
#8  0x400b1c in MAIN__
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/link_alloc.f90:64
#9  0x400b1c in main
    at /home/ijb/work/stack/link_alloc.f90:55
Segmentation fault
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $
```

Fixing points 2 and 3 above by using a pointer for the new node, and explicitly initialising the pointers, leads to

```
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ cat link_pointer.f90
Module CLASS_LIST

  Private

  Type :: NODE
     Real :: Value
     Type(NODE), Pointer :: NEXT => Null()
  End Type NODE

  Type, Public :: LIST
     Type(NODE), Pointer :: HEAD => Null()
   Contains
     Procedure :: APPEND
     Procedure :: Print
  End Type LIST

Contains

  Subroutine APPEND(THIS, Value)
    Class(LIST), Intent(INOUT) :: THIS
    Real, Intent(IN) :: Value
    Type(NODE), Pointer :: LINK
    Allocate(LINK)
    LINK%Value = Value
    LINK%NEXT => THIS%HEAD
    THIS%HEAD => LINK
  End Subroutine APPEND

  Subroutine Print( this )

    Class( list ), Intent( In ) :: this

    Call descend( this%head )

  Contains

    Recursive Subroutine descend( head )

      Type( node ), Intent( In ) :: head

      Write( *, '( f5.0, 1x )' ) head%value

      If( Associated( head%next ) ) Then
         Call descend( head%next )
      End If

    End Subroutine descend

  End Subroutine Print

End Module CLASS_LIST

Program MAIN

  Use CLASS_LIST

  Type(LIST) :: A
  Integer :: I

  Do I = 1, 5, 1
     Call A%APPEND(Real(I))
  End Do

  Call a%print

End Program MAIN
```

This compiles without warning and runs correctly repeatedly:

```
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -O -g link_pointer.f90 -o link_pointer
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./link_pointer 
   5.
   4.
   3.
   2.
   1.
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./link_pointer 
   5.
   4.
   3.
   2.
   1.
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./link_pointer 
   5.
   4.
   3.
   2.
   1.
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./link_pointer 
   5.
   4.
   3.
   2.
   1.
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./link_pointer 
   5.
   4.
   3.
   2.
   1.
ijb@ianbushdesktop ~/work/stack $ ./link_pointer 
   5.
   4.
   3.
   2.
   1.
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it helped me understand a lit bit more about Fortran. So in my original code, the local variable `LINK` was being automatically deallocated when out of scope. The solution was to make it a pointer, which doesn't get automatically deallocated, correct? Just one thing, in your updated code, `Type(NODE), Pointer :: LINK` should also be initialized with `=> null()`, correct?

Comment: Be careful, initializing the local variable will make it saved.

Comment: Yes, pointers don't automatically get deallocated. But initialising the local variable causes a problem as VladimirF points out, as initialisation causes the variable to gain the save attribute, which is not what you want - you want a different pointer each time which persists beyond the end of the subroutine